# Organizing Activity in Android. States. Easy?

Tags: android, android-activity

Please have a look at the graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2lfN.png

I have some trouble with the architecture of my app. I have a few Activity/states that if you reach them you are not allowed to go back. These are **K**, **A** and **X**, so when you reach them and press back button you will close my app.

It is very easy with **START** Activity. As soon as I do some work to decide if I go to **K** or **A**, I just run **START**.finish() and that is what I want (being in **K** or **A** Activity and pressing back button closes app as **START** Activity no longer exist).

The problem starts with **X** state. The application is like you need to fullfill 3 steps so you go through:

[**START**]->[**A**<->**B**<->**C**]->[**X**]

The requirements are while pressing back button:

on **A**: closes app

on **B**: show A

on **C**: show B

If you then finally finish some kind of wizard (**A**->**B**->**C**) you reach **X** where if you only press back button you closes app.

**QUESTION: How should I finish() A, B, C to prevent back button from X? I have no reference to use.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this, is in  activity X, make pressing the back button fire of a custom event.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        backPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void backPressed()
{
   Globals.finished = true;
   finish();
}
```

You'll notice the above method has the line **Globals.finished = true;** This refers to a class called Global with a static (static can be called on a class without having to instantiate an object) boolean variable called finished that is initially set to false as follows. In my own apps I often use a Globals class for sharing things common to the whole app. You can also used the shared preferences to do somthing similar.

```
public class Globals
{
  public static finished = false;
}
```

Then in the onResume (or possibly onStart)  lifecycle method of all activities you can put the following

```
if (Globals.finished == true)
    finish();
```

This will cause, all the activities to immediately close, but only once the finish variable in the Globals is true. I've done this before and it works quite well and will ensure the activities call their life cycle methods on closing.

Even simpler than this, you could avoid the use of the back button event handler, by setting the Globals.finished = true, in the onClose method of ActivityX.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `finish()` all the way back in the activities you want to be finished. use **startActivityForResult** to help you with back'n'finish process

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. Finishing them is clear for me. But how could I finish A, B, C as I have no reference? This is what I really do not understand well in Android. Activities are not same as windows because in other GUI frameworks, I have references to my windows so I can do whatever I want. Now I feel like Activities hang somewhere in the air and If I only change one I am not in control on previuos ones. Will you please be that kind and write more preciously what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

you can add  android:noHistory="true" in the manifeast file for activity A,B,C that is...

sample code for manifeast look like

```
<activity android:label="string resource" android:name="activityA" android:noHistory="true" />
```